# Browser Login Form

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to find how to use the Chrome/IE basic login authentication form for an asp.net page. I can find lots of examples of custom built login controls and forms where the web.config and redirects to the page, eg

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">
  </forms>

</authentication>
```

How do I do this using so it looks like the following? (1st image is in Chrome, second is in IE). I'm aware this isn't secure but just wanted to know how it's done.

[image: Chrome Login]
[image: IE Login]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use Windows Authentication (not Forms Authentication) to make this happen, at least on IIS 8 and earlier.

Comment: Thank you, it's easy when you know what to look for!